# Ошибка Call to undefined method SQLite3Result::fetch_array()

Tags: php, sqlite3

Как правильно использовать fetch_array?

Вот код.

```
if ($result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contents")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
    $total = $row[0];
    $result->close();
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Call to undefined method SQLite3Result::fetch_array()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не когда не работал с SQLite, но вроде в документации [fetchArray()](http://php.net/manual/ru/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php), у вас функция не правильная!

```
$row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
var_dump($row);
```

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка была именно в симоле _
Перевожу движок с Mysql на sqlite3

Comment: Рад, что помогло!

Comment: Если делаете перевод, используйте лучше PDO, в будущем при смене движка, таких проблем не будет!